# Cómo operar en algunas celdas de una matriz?

Tags: python, pandas, condiciones, bucles, numpy

Tengo dos matrices una **A** y una **B**.

Necesito modificar los valores en la matriz B (restarles -3.0) que sean menores a los valores de la matriz **A**, los valores de las demás celdas debo dejarlas igual, me explico:

```
A = Raster_A.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
B = Raster_B.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()

A = array([ 917.985028, 916.284480, 918.525323, 920.709505,
            921.835315, 922.328555, 920.283029, 922.229594,
            922.928670, 925.315534, 922.280360, 922.715303,
            925.933969, 925.897328, 923.880606, 923.864701])

B = array([ 913.75785758,  914.45941854,  915.17586919,  915.90724705,
            916.6534542 ,  917.4143068 ,  918.18957846,  918.97902532,
            919.78239295,  920.59941086,  921.42978108,  922.27316565,
            923.12917544,  923.99736194,  924.87721232,  925.76814782])
```

He intentado este código, pero se demora demasiado e igual no me da el resultado que busco:

```
for i in np.nditer(A, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    for j in np.nditer(B, op_flags=['readwrite']):
        if j[...] > i[...]:
            B = j[...]-3.0
```

Y este, es el resultado que busco. Que se me modifiquen únicamente los valores en **B** que sean menores a los valores que en **A**. La matriz **A** queda intacta:

```
B = array([ 913.75785758,  914.45941854,  915.17586919,  915.90724705,
            916.6534542 ,  917.4143068 ,  918.18957846,  918.97902532,
            919.78239295,  920.59941086,  921.42978108,  922.27316565,
            923.12917544,  923.99736194,  921.87721232,  922.76814782])
```

Los dos valores a la extrema inferior derecha, son los que fueron modificados (se les restó -3.0).

Cualquier respuesta que me sirva de ayuda es muy apreciada gracias! :)

Comment: ¿Estás intentando restarle 3.0 a cada valor en B, si el valor en la misma posición en A es mayor? Si ese es el caso: ¿Por qué recorres B por cada elemento en A?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pides:

> A los valores en la matriz B (restarles -3.0) que sean menores a los
> valores de la matriz A

Puedes aprovechar el [Boolean array indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) para seleccionar los elementos a partir de la evaluación de una condición, en este caso los elemento de B menores de A:

```
B[B < A] = B[B < A] - 3
```

Lo interesante que puedes usarlo tanto en la selección como en la asignación.